# Measure runtime of start-process with parameters

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a script that runs the following commands:

```
$result = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $proc $args
```

I want to measure how long it takes. Based on [this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/measure-the-run-time-of-a-powershell-command-with-measure-command/), I am trying the following:

```
$buildtime = measure-command -expression { $result = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $proc $args }
```

Unfortunately, it throws the following error:

> ```
> Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of
> the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try
> the command again.
> At C:\!scripts\pullandbuild.ps1:78 char:90
> + ... d -expression { $result = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $proc $args }
> +                                                                   ~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
> ```

Due to other issues I had with strings and variable expansion, `$args` is defined like this:

```
$args = @"
& -quit -batchmode -logFile "$logfile" -buildWindows64Player "$($fullpath)\Project.exe"
"@
```

How can I fix this? Or is there another way to capture the runtime of the script?  I'm trying to learn PS so I'd rather avoid just capturing the time before I run it and after I run and comparing, but if that's my only option I will.

Comment: Don't write to `$args` manually, it's an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#args)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[stivix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539504/45375) contains the crucial pointer - **`$args` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) that shouldn't be used as a custom variable** - but it's worth digging deeper:

**`$args` is automatically set to the array (`[object[]]`) of positional arguments passed to a [simple script [block] or function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#simple-functions)**<sup>[1]</sup>, inside that code unit; if no arguments are passed, `$args` contains an empty array.

Since you cannot pass arguments intended to be seen by a script block passed to `Measure-Command`'s `-Expression` parameter, `$args` is by definition the empty array inside that script block, which caused `Start-Process` to fail.

As an aside: That `Start-Process` *fails* with an empty array - instead of interpreting it as "no arguments to pass" - is a problem in *Windows PowerShell* that has since been corrected in PowerShell *Core*.

**That PowerShell even *lets you* assign a value to `$args` is problematic.**
Unfortunately, this is part of a **larger problem of not preventing custom use of automatic variables** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58820780/45375).

The insidious aspect of this behavior is that the problem doesn't surface until you enter a script [block] or function; in the *caller's* scope the custom value assigned to `$args` *does* take effect, as the following example shows:

```
$args = 'hi'  # !! To be avoided. Assign a custom value to $args
# Echo the custom value, in the same scope.
"after assignment: [$args]"         
# Call a script block and echo $args there. 
& { "in script block: [$args]; element count: $($args.Count)" }
```

The above yields:

```
after assignment: [hi]
in script block: []; element count: 0
```

The 1st output line shows that the assignment in the *caller's* scope worked as expected.

The 2nd output line shows that `$args` was automatically set to an empty array upon entering the script block, because no arguments were passed to the script block (`{ ... }`).

Note: Technically, a *local* `$args` variable is created inside the script block, and the caller's copy is still accessible if you access the caller's scope explicitly (e.g. via `(Get-Variable args -Scope 1 -ValueOnly)`), but the more sensible approach is to avoid custom use of `$args` altogether.

---

<sup>[1] `$args` only contains those arguments that aren't bound to *explicitly declared* parameters, if any. In [*advanced* script or functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced), you may only ever pass arguments to explicitly defined parameters, so `$args` is *not* defined there, because its use would be pointless; in fact, in an advanced script / function `$args` *does* retain a caller's *custom* `$args` definition if run in the same scope domain, but that shouldn't be relied upon.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I just checked, your $args variable is empty, turns out $args is a built-in variable. Once I changed variable name, it's not null anymore, try that.

How about you try one of these approaches:

1.

```
$startTime = Get-Date
$processToRun = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru -Wait
$finishTime = Get-Date
$timeDifference = New-TimeSpan -Start $startTime -End $finishTime
```

2. Use StartTime and ExitTime properties of $result, then compare times using New-Timespan

Comment: Re other approaches: Using `Get-Date` is handy, especially if you do want to see command output, but note that it's better to use `(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()` or, in PSv5+,  `[datetime]::UtcNow`. `Measure-Command` uses more accurate timing, though that will probably rarely matter in practice.
Note that you can directly subtract 2 `[datetime]` instances to get a `[timespan]` instance (`$finishTime - $startTime`) - no need for `New-TimeSpan`.
A caveat re `System.Diagnostics.Process.StartTime`: it doesn't work on Unix-like platforms in PowerShell Core and returns `$null`.

Answer (score -1):

To put quotes:

"Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $proc $args"

should be:

$buildtime = measure-command -expression {$results = "Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $proc $args"}

and

'@ & -quit -batchmode "-logFile $logfile" -buildWindows64Player "$($fullpath)\Project.exe"@'

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: What you're proposing is an _expandable string_, not a command to be executed.