# How to pass parameters to a PS script invoked through Start-Job?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, automatic-variable

I want to use start-job to run a .ps1 script requiring a parameter. Here's the script file:

```
#Test-Job.ps1 
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$input
)

$output = "$input to output"

return $output
```

and here is how I am running it:

```
$input = "input"
Start-Job -FilePath 'C:\PowerShell\test_job.ps1' -ArgumentList $input -Name "TestJob"
Get-Job -name "TestJob" | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
Get-Job -name "TestJob" | Remove-Job
```

Run like this, it returns " to output", so $input is null in the script run by the job.

I've seen other questions similar to this, but they mostly use -Scriptblock in place of -FilePath. Is there a different method for passing parameters to files through Start-Job?

Comment: `$Input` is a reserved automatic variable. DO NOT use it as anything other than a read-only item. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- `$input` is an *automatic variable* (value supplied by PowerShell) and shouldn't be used as a custom variable.
- Simply renaming `$input` to, say, `$InputObject` solves your problem.

---

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) notes, **[`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) and *shouldn't be assigned to*** (it is automatically managed by PowerShell to provide an enumerator of pipeline input in non-advanced scripts and functions).

Regrettably and **unexpectedly, *several* automatic variables, including `$input`, *can* be assigned to**: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58820780/45375).

`$input` is a particularly insidious example, because if you use it as a *parameter* variable, any value you pass to it is *quietly discarded*, because in the context of a function or script `$input` invariably is an enumerator for any *pipeline input*.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate the problem:

```bash
PS> & { param($input) "[$input]" } 'hi'
 # !! No output - the argument was quietly discarded.
```

That the built-in definition of `$input` takes precedence can be demonstrated as follows:

```bash
PS> 'ho' | & { param($input) "[$input]" } 'hi'
ho # !! pipeline input took precedence
```

---

While you can technically get away with using `$input` as a *regular* variable (rather than a parameter variable) *as long as you don't cross scope boundaries*, custom use of `$input` should still be avoided:

```bash
& {
  $input = 'foo'   # TO BE AVOIDED
  "[$input]"       # Technically works: -> '[foo]'
  & { "[$input]" } # FAILS, due to child scope: -> '[]'
}
```